# How to apply "sendAlertEmailWhenCellValueIsNotEmpty" script to multiple tabs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to apply this to let's say "Weekly" and "Monthly" tab.
Here's my script:

```
function sendAlertEmailWhenCellValueIsNotEmpty(){
  //send an email alert when cellToWatch is not empty
  //set this function to run through a time driven trigger
  //choose resource> Current project's triggers> Add a new trigger>Time-driven>Day Timer
  //see https://productforums.google/d/topic/docs/39Ysmg7nAjk/discussion

  //edit the following variable to fit your needs
  var cellToWatch="DAILY!W12";
  var mailAddress="someone@gmail.com";
  var emailSubject="Spreadsheet alert:BECKMAN COULTER UNICEL DXI800 MISSING DAILY MAINTENANCE";
      var emailBody="This is an email alert from your google spreadsheet:BECKMAN COULTER UNICEL DXI800 MISSING DAILY MAINTENANCE" 

  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellToWatch).getValue()!=""){
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,emailSubject,emailBody);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Webapps. It looks to me that you got this code from somewhere. But do not know how to read it. Please use the answer below as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

In the script it is mentioned:

```
//edit the following variable to fit your needs
  var cellToWatch="DAILY!W12";
  var mailAddress="someone@gmail.com";
  var emailSubject="Spreadsheet alert:BECKMAN COULTER UNICEL DXI800 MISSING DAILY MAINTENANCE";
      var emailBody="This is an email alert from your google spreadsheet:BECKMAN COULTER UNICEL DXI800 MISSING DAILY MAINTENANCE"
```

- The variable `var`defined in `cellToWatch="DAILY!W12"` refers to cell `W12` on sheet `DAILY`
- `mailAddress="someone@gmail.com"` mentions who the email will be sent to
- `emailSubject="Spreadsheet alert:BECKMAN ....` is the Subject of the email
- `emailBody="This is an email....` is the body of the email.

Play around with these variables and see what you get.

**And please start reading [about scripting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)**.